# не работает pod install после обновления на Catalina

Tags: xcode, консоль, cocoapods

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.8.4) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.6.0). Incompatibility issues may arise.
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно удалить podfile.lock, затем в терминале еще раз запустить pod install. У меня после этого возникла ошибка в Xcode [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это получилось решить так

Xcode->File->Project/Workspace settings->Change the build system to Legacy Build system.

Вместо этого можно просто удалить frameworks из Target->Embed Pods Frameworks[image: введите сюда описание изображения]